# Сетевые интерфейсы

Tags: сеть

Начинаю разбираться с Solaris и администрированием вообще. Как работать с сетевыми интерфейсами из командной строки: например, получить их список, задать сетевую маску для какого-либо интерфейса и т.д.? И еще интересно, чего лучше не делать с СИ (отчего они могут перестать работать)?

Answer (score 1):

Получить список можно командой `ifconfig`

Далее, используя эту команду с именем интерфейса вы получаете информации о нем:

> ifconfig hme0

С интерфейсами так же можно дружить, а можно их "ложить" и "поднимать" командами `down` и `up`

> ifconfig hme0 downifconfig hme0 up

Смена IP:

> ifconfig hme0 128.50.1.2 -trailers up

Смена маски:

> ifconfig hme0 down && ifconfig hme0 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast + up

И так далее, остальное и про другие команды, найдете по сей [ссылке](http://www.softpanorama.org/Net/Netutils/ifconfig_in_solaris.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

Сначала нужно посмотреть состав оборудования: сосчитать количество и имена сетевых карт:    prtconf

Потом посмотреть какие интерфейсы уже настроены:ifconfig -a

Не настроенные аппаратные сетевые интерфейсы настраиваются командой: ifconfig plumb "имя интерфеса"

"Имя интерфейса" берётся из вывода команды prtconf. Также оно совпадает с именем модуля ядра Solaris (драйвера). См. вывод команды `modinfo`

Также командой `ifconfig plumb` можно создавать интерфейсы-алиасы (добавлять новые IP, на существующие порты) и VLAN-интерфейсы.